# How to replace specific parts of string contain numbers with a matching dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I would like to replace specific parts of string containing numbers with a dictionary. Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
d = {7: 'mandat_dépôt', 46: 'battu', 79: 'alphabétisé', 127: 'escrime', 160: 'daara', 162: 'arrivée_foyer', 169: 'fugue', 170: 'né_légitimement'}
```

I have these kinds of string:

```
s_1 = "7 ==> 127 #SUP: 41 #CONF: 0.8723404255319149"
s_2 = "46 ==> 162,169 #SUP: 39 #CONF: 0.8478260869565217"
s_3 = "46,169 ==> 162 #SUP: 39 #CONF: 0.975"
s_4 = "160,169 ==> 79,162 #SUP: 40 #CONF: 0.7692307692307693"
s_5 = "160,162,170 ==> 79 #SUP: 39 #CONF: 0.8125"
```

Expected strings:

```
new_s_1 = "mandat_dépôt ==> escrime #SUP: 41 #CONF: 0.8723404255319149"
new_s_2 = "battu ==> arrivée_foyer,fugue #SUP: 39 #CONF: 0.8478260869565217"
new_s_3 = "battu,fugue ==> arrivée_foyer #SUP: 39 #CONF: 0.975"
new_s_4 = "daara,fugue ==> alphabétisé,arrivée_foyer #SUP: 40 #CONF: 0.7692307692307693"
new_s_5 = "daara,arrivée_foyer,né_légitimement ==> alphabétisé #SUP: 39 #CONF: 0.8125"
```

Note that i don't want to replace the value of #SUP even if there exists some keys in the the dictionary.

Is there an effective way to do it?

Comment: Split by `' '`, then for element 0 and element 2 split by `,`, then look up in `d`, then join everything back to string

Comment: element 0 and element 2 are not enough and general for all types of string.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is an effective way but here is my codes:

```
old_s = [s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5]
new_s = []

for i in old_s:
    number, string = i.split('#SUP:')
    number = number.split("==>")
    number = [r.strip() for r in number]
    number = [r.split(",") for r in number]
    text_number = []
    for r in number:
        each_text_number = []
        for item in r:
            each_text_number.append(d[int(item)])
        text_number.append(each_text_number)
    front_number = ','.join(front_num for front_num in text_number[0])
    back_number = ','.join(back_num for back_num in text_number[1])
    text_rule_string = front_number + " ==> " + back_number + " #SUP:" + string
    new_s.append(text_rule_string)
print(new_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

1- split the string by " "
2- loop over them and check which ones is an instance of your dict;  if True replace with
3- join the string back by " "
If there are keys you want to exclude, you will need to add additional check for them.

**Example code**

```py
d = {7: 'mandat_dépôt', 46: 'battu', 79: 'alphabétisé', 127: 'escrime', 160: 'daara', 162: 'arrivée_foyer', 169: 'fugue', 170: 'né_légitimement'}

s_1 = "7 ==> 127 #SUP: 41 #CONF: 0.8723404255319149"


n_1 = " ".join([d.get(int(ni)) if ni.isnumeric() and d.get(int(ni))  else ni for ni in s_1.split(" ") ])
print(n_1)
```

Comment: Your code only worked for s_1

Comment: You will need to make a split on each string again by "," in the others, it is simply obvious!

Answer (score 0):

```
def converter(string: str) -> str:
    number, string = string.split('#SUP:')
    first, last = number.split("==>")
    first = ','.join([d[int(j)] for j in first.split(',')])
    last = ','.join([d[int(j)] for j in last.split(',')])
    return f"{first} ==> {last} #SUP:{string}"


new_s_1 = converter(s_1)
new_s_2 = converter(s_2)
etc...
```

Comment: Can you verify with the expected outputs? It seems that the numbers behind the ==> did not convert to the letters.

Comment: i have update the code sorry for the error